# Derivative of a polygon

Tags: boost, polygon, computational-geometry, boost-polygon

I am studying boost polygon library,

however I can not understand how each vertexes are generated,

image: http://imm.io/LlIM

what is the rules for derivative of a polygon?

the original paper is:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/polygon/doc/GTL_boostcon2009.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit easier to follow in the manhattan-polygon example in [the presentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/polygon/doc/GTL_boostcon_draft03.pdf) (page 33).  The author later submitted a paper to the CAD journal entitled "Industrial strength polygon clipping: A novel algorithm with applications in VLSI CAD" (I found the PDF using [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?hs=LAW&q=polygon%20sdarticle_012.pdf)) which detailed the derivative process as follows:
[image: Vertex derivatives] and the accompanying figure: [image]